# Зависает компьютер, но звук продолжает идти; Из-за чего это может быть?

Tags: железо

Проблема заключается в том, что ПК зависает без какой-либо закономерности. Абсолютно рандомно.
При этом когда ПК зависает звук из игр, браузера или видео продолжает идти. ПК может отвиснуть и потом снова повторить зависание, но чаще он просто зависает намертво.
2 Раза был синий экран, но в винде нет какой либо информации из-за чего произошел синий.

**Железо:**

- CPU - Ryzen 7 2700 (Приобретен в декабре 2019 года)
- GPU - PowerColor Radeon RX 590 Red Devil (Приобретена в декабре 2019 года)
- ОЗУ - Geil EVO X 2x8 Gb, CL 16-16-16-36, 2400MHz (Приобретена 30.11.2018)
- Материнская плата - ASRock B450 Gaming K4 (Приобретена в декабре 2019 года)
- Блок питания - be quiet! System Power 9 600W (Приобретен в декабре 2019 года)
- Кулер на процессоре - be quiet! Pure Rock (Приобретен в декабре 2019 года)
- Системный SSD - Transcend 128Gb SSD340 (TS128GSSD340K) (Приобретен в 2017 году)
- NVME SSD - Apacer AS2280P4 480Gb (Приобретен 23.11.2020)
- Также был установлен HDD WD Green 5400 об/мин 1000Gb (Приобретен очень давно, возможно лет 6-7 назад), но он после одного из зависаний перестал появляться в виндовс и биосе(хотя однажды он появился как USB накопитель). Сейчас этот жесткий диск отключен от материнки.
- Продув корпуса выше среднего - 2 вертушки на вдув спереди корпуса, 2 сверху и одна сзади корпуса на выдув

**Компьютер никак не разгонялся**(только активирован XMP на оперативке 2400MHz CL16-16-16-36 CR1).

Проблем с перегревом комплектующих нет. Разве что видеокарта греется до 75-80 когда в помещении жарко.

Винду переустановил 2 недели назад, поставил только самое минимальное - Word, PowerPoint, Браузер и программу от Autodesk которая нужна для работы 3DS MAX.

На втором SSD который NVME установлен Steam, Origin, Premiere Pro, AfterEffect, Photoshop, 3DS MAX и Battle.net.

**Все драйвера ставил с официальных сайтов и с помощью утилиты от AMD - Radeon Software**

**Прикрепляю различные тесты:**
Тест Aida64 на стабильность:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в VictoriaHDD системного SSD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в VictoriaHDD второго SSD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в OCCT CPU:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в OCCT GPU:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в OCCT Memory:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест в OCCT Памяти видеокарты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во время всех тестов было всего одно зависание - во время теста Aida64 на стабильность, но после этого я повторил тест еще 3 раза по 15+ минут и вылетов не было.
**Еще раз повторюсь - нет какой либо закономерности в зависаниях.** Они могут происходить когда играю, когда сижу в браузере, когда открываю какую-либо папку и даже когда он простаивает.

Прошу помочь с этой ситуацией, потому как гадать и покупать комплектующие которые не принесут результата не хочется.(Тем более сейчас когда все железо втридорога продается)

Comment: ECC DDR в биосе включен?

Comment: Настройки биоса сброшены, только активирован XMP. Не смог найти в биосе функцию ECC, не подскажите где в биосе asrock находится эта настройка?

Comment: Не знаю (может быть плата вообще не поддерживает ECC). / Попробуйте просто вынуть память и протереть контакты.

Comment: Если помогло, отпишитесь, плз

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Комп и так чистый был(как железо, так и система). Достал оперативу и почистил контакты, продул комп еще раз. Также вынул видяху и там все тоже почистил. При следующей загрузке он проработал без вылетов 2-3 часа, потом завис. После перезапуска начал запускать нужные проги и он просто завис и перезагрузился сам.